# Trying to change an exhortation into a prayer

Tags: adjetivos

How would I change this exhortation from the Bible into a prayer?
Hebreos 4:16 Nueva Versión Internacional (NVI)

"Así que acerquémonos confiadamente al trono de la gracia para recibir misericordia y hallar la gracia que nos ayude en el momento que más la necesitemos."

and this: "Acerquémonos, pues, confiadamente al trono de la gracia, para alcanzar misericordia y hallar gracia para el oportuno socorro."--
RVR1960

Would it be this? "Gracias, Dios, que podemos acercar confiadamente al trono de la gracia, para alcanzar misericordia y hallar gracia para el oportuno socoro."

Or would the following be better: "Asi a tu trono de la gracia podemos reciber misericordia y hallar la gracia que nos ayude en el momento que mas la necesitamos."?

Comment: Hello Jck and welcome to [Spanish.SE]! I am not sure to understand your question. Gramatically speaking, what is a prayer? Every one prays differently, there is no gramatically proper way to pray. Besides, your first option seems more a gratitude than a prayer. Maybe you would like to refine your question a bit? Check the [ask] page for more information.

Comment: I feel that what your question lacks, @Jck Gutknecht, is what the intention of the prayer is: is the prayer intended as adoration, thanksgiving, supplication? Depending on the intention, different verbs and verb forms can be chosen.

Comment: The prayer is intended as adoration or thanksgiving rather than supplication.

Comment: I would like Gustavson to try to answer my original question with this updated comment to his answer:  The prayer is intended as adoration or thanksgiving rather than supplication.

Comment: How do I find the email of Gustavson?